# Show that $C_n\times K_2$ is $1$-factorable for $n\ge4$

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation

Show that $C_n\times K_2$ is $1$-factorable (has a perfect matching) for $n\ge4.$
$\times$ means the Cartesian product.
$C_n$ means a cycle where $n=$ number of vertices of the cycle.
$K_2$ means the complete graph of order $n=2.$

I know when $C_n$ is even it is one-factorable. I also know $K_2$ is one-factorable. I have no idea how to prove the Cartesian product of such graphs is possible. I was thinking induction, but couldn't seem to get it right. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's the definition of the graph product X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will show that, if $G$ is any graph, then the Cartesian product $G\times K_2$ has a perfect matching. (In particular, $C_n\times K_2$ has a perfect matching for any $n\ge3.$)

Suppose $G$ is a graph of order $n.$ Let $\overline{K_n}$ be the complement of the complete graph $K_n,$ i.e., $\overline{K_n}$ is a graph with $n$ vertices and no edges.

It is easy to see that the Cartesian product $H=\overline{K_n}\times K_2$ is $1$-factorable; the graph $H$ is $1$-regular, so the whole edge-set $E(H)$ is a perfect matching.

The graph $\overline{K_n}$ is a spanning subgraph of $G,$ and so the graph $H=\overline{K_n}\times K_2$ is a spanning subgraph of $G\times K_2,$ and the perfect matching of $H$ is also a perfect matching of $G\times K_2.$

A similar argument shows that, if $G$ is any graph and $F$ is a $1$-factorable graph, then the Cartesian product $G\times F$ is $1$-factorable.